# How to subtract [[Float]] with another [Float] in swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to subtract the two float arrays.

```
let array1 = [[0,5.2000003,0.44705883,0,0,0,1.882353,0,0.49411765,0,0,0,0,0,2.447059,1.5294118,0,0,0,4.5176473],[0,5.2000003,0.44705883,0,0,0,1.882353,0,0.49411765,0,0,0,0,0,2.447059,1.5294118,0,0,0,4.5176473],[0,5.2000003,0.44705883,0,0,0,1.882353,0,0.49411765,0,0,0,0,0,2.447059,1.5294118,0,0,0,4.5176473]]
let array2 = [0.23529412, 1.7411765, 0.23529412, 0.0, 0.28235295, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5882353, 0.87058824, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.1529412]
```

The desired output I want is array2 should be subtracted from all the elements from array1. Is there to avoid forloop?

```
 Output expected : [[-0.23529412, 3.4588237, 0.21176471, 0.0, -0.28235295, 0.0, 1.882353, -0.5882353, -0.3764706, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.447059, 1.5294118, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.364706], [-0.23529412, 3.4588237, 0.21176471, 0.0, -0.28235295, 0.0, 1.882353, -0.5882353, -0.3764706, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.447059, 1.5294118, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.364706], [-0.23529412, 3.4588237, 0.21176471, 0.0, -0.28235295, 0.0, 1.882353, -0.5882353, -0.3764706, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.447059, 1.5294118, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.364706]]
```

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`zip(_:_:)`** and **`map(_:)`** on `array1` and `array2`, i.e.

```
let array3 = zip(array1, array2).map({ $0.0 - $0.1 })

print(array3) //[-0.23529412, 3.4588238000000002, 0.21176471000000002, 0.0, -0.28235295, 0.0, 1.882353, -0.5882353, -0.37647059, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.447059, 1.5294118, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3647061000000003]
```

**Edit:**

If the `array1` and `array2` are of type `[[Float]]` and `[Float]`,

```
let array1 = [[0,5.2000003,0.44705883,0,0,0,1.882353,0,0.49411765,0,0,0,0,0,2.447059,1.5294118,0,0,0,4.5176473],[0,5.2000003,0.44705883,0,0,0,1.882353,0,0.49411765,0,0,0,0,0,2.447059,1.5294118,0,0,0,4.5176473],[0,5.2000003,0.44705883,0,0,0,1.882353,0,0.49411765,0,0,0,0,0,2.447059,1.5294118,0,0,0,4.5176473]]
let array2 = [0.23529412, 1.7411765, 0.23529412, 0.0, 0.28235295, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5882353, 0.87058824, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.1529412]

let output = array1.map({ return zip($0, array2).map({ $0.0 - $0.1 }) }) //[[-0.23529412, 3.4588238000000002, 0.21176471000000002, 0.0, -0.28235295, 0.0, 1.882353, -0.5882353, -0.37647059, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.447059, 1.5294118, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3647061000000003], [-0.23529412, 3.4588238000000002, 0.21176471000000002, 0.0, -0.28235295, 0.0, 1.882353, -0.5882353, -0.37647059, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.447059, 1.5294118, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3647061000000003], [-0.23529412, 3.4588238000000002, 0.21176471000000002, 0.0, -0.28235295, 0.0, 1.882353, -0.5882353, -0.37647059, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.447059, 1.5294118, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3647061000000003]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for such a quick reply. It worked brother.

Comment: Great. Do accept if the answer helped. Happy coding..

Comment: What if I want to subtract [[Float]] from [Float]? How is this possible?

Comment: @ZubinGala Give an example with the expected output.

Comment: The desired output I want is array2 should be subtracted from all the elements from array1.

Comment: @ZubinGala Add the inputs as well. And add it in the question.